# What is the difference between these two integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$1)$ $$\int_R 3 ~dxdy$$

$2)$ $$\iint_R 3xy~ dxdy$$

They both seem to be computed in the same way so I guess I don't understand why we use sometimes one integral and two other times.

Comment: further more to the answer below..but imagine doing an integral over an $n$ dimensional object? where $n$ is possibly large? it gets tiresome ;) and inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious difference that $3 \neq 3xy$, hence these are integrating different functions, there is no difference. Sometimes we use one integral to mean integrating over some region, regardless of its dimension. Sometimes we use a double integral to make it explicit that this is an integral over a two-dimensional region.

Comment: Okay thanks the notes I am using keep switching between the two so I was confused at first.